# Render mongodb documents with varying schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, ejs

Has anyone come across an elegant way/library to render Mongodb documents with varying schema ? 
I am basically using NodeJS+Express+EJS and would like to display a number of documents. The document schema is not fixed so solutions like Datatables would have been ideal but requires the columns to be fixed. I am trying to see if anyone has come across an innovative way of dealing with this problem in a way thats also visually attractive and user friendly for the end user.
Every document has an _id and _created. So perhaps I render a list of these and once clicked it opens and shows all the other fields which could be different document to document. 
Thanks
Tony

Answer (score 0):

What you mentioned at the end is the convention, as far as I know. It's not something you may do but you should. Show the minimum and the most important information of records in a list. User clicks one to get more of its detail in a new page, dialog, or expanded screen. This is what we see in most of the web and mobile apps.

The URLs for pages and Restful APIs also follow this convention `resource/`, `resource/id` and `api/resource`, `api/resource/id`.

In case the fields are not that many and you absolutely require full info per record in the list, then you can follow some scheme like below. It takes into account variable fields:

```
//example mongodb documents
var docs = [{
        _id: "59608c980b526c5e0d72f30f",
        firstName: "Steve",
        lastName: "Smith",
        fullName: "Steve A Smith"

    },
    {
        _id: "59608c980b526c5e0d72f300",
        firstName: "John",
        lastName: "Steward",
        address: "Park Lane",
        email: "j_stwd@gmail.com"

    }];
```

On view (ejs with `?` as delimiter)

```
    <div class="row">
        <? docs.forEach(function(doc, index) { ?>
          <? for(var key in doc){ ?>
              <?= key !== '_id'? (key + ": " + doc[key]) : "" ?> <br>
          <? } ?>
        <? }) ?>
    </div>
```

[image]

You would obviously want to put each record in some card or container and beautify it. Also, maybe split the key names or map them to more human friendly format like `First Name` instead of `firstName`.

Comment: Thanks Talha, was hoping there was a nice library that can do all the heavy lifting as the data is readily available over an API end point

Comment: The question remains the same: Should you really show all the fields of a document in the list (table, card whatever)? You can guess by the absence of any reputable library that it's not a desirable behavior. However, if you don't even have a few fields apart from `_id` that are guaranteed to exist in all documents then you have a point. But in any dynamic rendering you are either bound to mention field names for each document separately (as I showed above) or take union of all fields from all the documents and convert them to a table row and show respective values underneath.

Comment: @TonyAldo The only library I could find that does something similar to what you require is [mongo-table-admin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongo-table-admin). It appears to be test-only for admin, so not of real use.

Comment: The data represents a visitor form. While form fields dont change often, the admin may decide to add a field to the form. So the document schema isnt really strict.